# Peugeot 307 2006 model 35000 miles on the clock

Tags: peugeot, stall

The car is almost stalling when you are slowing down I restart the engine and  it starts again straightaway first time
The car looses all power for a couple of minutes if that.

The garage thinks it could be the crankshaft.
What is this and how expensive is it to repair?

Panicking for sure as I am disabled and   rely on a car to get me around.

Comment: Is it idling smoothly? Is it just slow vehicle speed and deceleration, or slow engine speed? You'll need to be much more specific. The crankshaft is the piece of the engine that converts the reciprocating motion of the pistons into the rotary motion the wheels need to turn. https://www.quora.com/What-is-a-crankshaft What are they suggesting is wrong with the crankshaft?

Comment: That doesn't sound correct. Take it to another mechanic to get a second opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the site @sarahDerbyshire, hopefully we can give you some good information. The crankshaft of an engine is what converts the up and down motion of the pistons into a rotation which can be transferred to the wheels, replacing a crankshaft is a big job as the entire engine must be removed from the car and stripped down to get to it, which is very labor intensive, it can often be cheaper to buy a used engine which is working and fitting that instead.

However, from your description of the problem the crankshaft is not the likely culprit. There are many other problems I would suspect like vacuum leaks, fuel supply issues, and ignition issues all of which would be much cheaper to fix. It's possible that the mechanics you have taken it to have better information than I do after seeing the car, however if I were you I would take it to a different garage for a second opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with GdD... Sarah... Take your car to another garage. Even a badly failing crank may give you bad oil pressure or cause a knocking sound etc, however its EXTREMELY unlikely to be the cause of a stalling problem.

The issue your having sounds far more likely to be a general tuning or fuel supply related issue.